# Stored information in class-based decorator in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, python-decorators

I am a beginner in Python, and learning Decorators from Lutz's book. I came across this code below. I am unsure why and how `tracer` retains the number of function calls even though new instance is created.

```
class tracer:
    def __init__(self,func):
        self.calls=0
        self.func=func
    def __call__(self, *args):
        self.calls+=1
        print('call %s to %s' %(self.calls,self.func.__name__))
        self.func(*args)

@tracer
def spam(a,b,c):
    print (a+b+c)

spam(1,2,3) #Here calls counter increments to 1
t= tracer(spam)
t.func(3,4,5) # here calls counter increments to 2 even though I called `spam` using new instance `t`

g=tracer(spam)
g.func(4,5,6)  #calls counter increments to 3.
```

As we can see above, the `calls` counter state is retained even though a new instance is created.

Can someone please explain why this is the case? I tried debugging the code using PyCharm, and it seems the memory location of `spam` remains the same, irrespective of calls by a particular instance.

---

I am using Python 3.6 from Anaconda Distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, while the assignments for `t` and `g` are indeed creating new instances, you are passing the same instance of the original wrapped function, `spam`. After being decorated, `spam` is no longer a function, instead it is an instance of `tracer`. That is how Python is design to handle the wrapping of class around an object: the object's name becomes an instance of the wrapping object.

---

Anytime `tracer(spam)` is created, the attribute `func` in `tracer` is an instance of the original wrapped function `spam`. Thus, when calling the wrapped value, `self.func(*args)` is called in `tracer.__call__`, triggering `func.__call__`, which increments `calls`.

The instances of `tracer`, `t` and `g`, are all being passed the same instance of `tracer`, `spam`, which is being assigned to the attribute `func`. Thus, `t.func` and `g.func` are all instances and thus reference `spam`, and all of its attributes. Therefore, when you call `t.func` and `g.func`, you are triggering `spam.__call__`, thus incrementing `calls` in `spam`:

```
class tracer:
   def __init__(self, _func):
     self.func = _func
     self.calls = 0
   def __repr__(self):
     return f"{self.__class__.__name__}(storing {self.func.__name__})"
   def __call__(self, *args):
      self.calls += 1
      print(f"__call__ executed in {repr(self)}")
      return self.func(*args)

@tracer
def spam(a,b,c):
  print (a+b+c)

>>>spam(1, 2, 3)
__call__ executed in tracer(storing spam)
t= tracer(spam)
>>>t.func(1, 2, 3)
__call__ executed in tracer(storing spam)
g=tracer(spam)
>>>g.func(1, 2, 3)
__call__ executed in tracer(storing spam)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It will be great if you could explain why is it that `self.func(*args)` is called in `tracer.__call__` although I created a new instance of `tracer`. It will be great if you could explain this with an example. I am very new to the world of Python, and have been struggling to self-learn.

Comment: @watchtower Please see my recent edit. I created a `repr` method in `tracer` to demonstrate what object is being called in `__call__`. As you can see, every time `t.func` and `g.func` are called, the instance `spam` is being accessed.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that `t` and `g` are doubly wrapped tracers. That is, they're one `tracer` instance containing another `tracer` instance (which finally refers to a function). The outer `tracer`s don't really work properly, since the inner `tracer` doesn't have a `__name__` attribute, since it's not a function. You can only call `t.func`, which bypasses the outer tracer (and its count) to call the inner one directly.

You could make the code work by adding a `__name__` attribute to each `tracer`:

```
class tracer:
    def __init__(self,func):
        self.calls=0
        self.func=func
        self.__name__ = 'tracer wrapping %r' % func.__name__   # give ourselves a name
    def __call__(self, *args):
        self.calls+=1
        print('call %s to %s' %(self.calls,self.func.__name__))
        self.func(*args)    # note, you should probably return the result of this call
```

Now you can call `t(3, 4, 5)` and `g(5, 6, 7)` and each call will print out two counts, one for the inner tracer and one for the outer. The outer counts will be separate (each starting at 1), but the inner ones will be shared (just like you were seeing originally).

Of course, it may be that you don't want the nested tracers. In that case, you probably want to remove the `@tracer` line from before the function. That's where the inner tracer gets applied, it's equivalent to putting `spam = tracer(spam)` after the definition for the `spam` function. Without that line, `spam` will just refer to the function directly (with no `tracer` wrapped around it), and `t` and `g` would be applied directly to the function, without an inner `tracer` getting in the way.

Comment: Thanks Blckknight. Could you please explain why `t and g are doubly wrapped tracers?` Aren't they independent objects?

Comment: It's because `spam` is already wrapped up once due to the `@tracer`. When you do `t = tracer(spam)`, you're putting a second wrapper around the first one.

Comment: @Blckknight. Thanks for your help. Is there any way we can track (or print) the two wrappers? I tried debugging the code, and I couldn't understand these doubly wrapped decorators. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure, `spam` is the inner wrapper. `t` and `g` are the two different outer wrappers. You can also get to the inner wrapper as `t.func` and `g.func`.